# how to build this structure with displays and without using floats

Tags: html, css

what is the html and css I should use for this layout (consider I don't want to use floats, and do want to use displays).

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to use floats?

Comment: Try absolute positioning. http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: from what I remember this can be done with only using display:inline-block and such,but I don't remember how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think this method is more work, it does work:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mg37W/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="one">
    </div>
    <div class="two">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 320px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid green;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.one, .two {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: brown;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can have three options:

1. Use tables to structure it the way you want - two rows with one column (with rowspan="2")
2. Position all three blocks in absolute positions
3. Use floats

The best and easy way is to use floats.

Comment: @jimmy who: wihtout more requirements, this is the best possible answer.